# abrir archivo csv con pandas sin usar rutas absolutas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Tengo que trabajar sobre un proyecto y necesito abrir el archivo csv sin usar rutas absolutas, lo he guardado en una carpeta llamada input y ahora mismo estoy trabajando sobre otra que se llama output cómo lo hago estoy probando esto:
`df = pd.read_csv('inputs/attacks.csv')`

*La carpeta inpus está a su vez dentro de otras carpetas

Comment: Eso debería funcionar, pero ten en cuenta que la ruta relativa se refiere a la carpeta desde la cual se lanza el script. Si lo lanzas desde línea de comandos, debes lanzarlo desde la carpeta que tiene `input` como subdirectorio. Si lo lanzas desde un IDE como VSCode, debes fijarte qué carpeta usa el IDE como directorio de trabajo.

Comment: uo input lo tengo dentro de una carpeta que se llama Shark_attack esta a su vez en una que se llama PROJECT1 y esta en otra que se llama PROJECTS_REPOS qué carpeta tengo que usar entonces??

Answer (score 0):

La solución que yo uso, para que no importe en qué ruta esté la consola actualmente es:

1. Recoger la ruta en la que está el archivo .py

```
import os
def_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

2. Concatenarlo con la ruta relativa que deseas

```
archivo = os.path.join(def_path, 'path/relativo/que/quieras')
```

O también lo puedes hacer como una función

```
def ruta_rel(ruta):
    d = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    return os.path.join(d, ruta)

df = pd.read_csv(ruta_rel('inputs/attacks.csv'))
```

Ten en cuenta que hacer esto implica sus propios problemas, por ejemplo, si vas a importar la función desde otro módulo, te dará la ruta del módulo que estás importando (no la del archivo que está siendo ejecutado), por lo que deberías tener cuidado en esos casos.